# Graph animation - How can I access individual faces via the API?

Tags: python, animation, image, faces

I want to create a visual representation for quite a lot of data. I did not stumble up on a tool to construct a 3D or 2D graph in Blender yet. If there is anything like that it would solve my problem and make the following question unnecessary. Having said this, here is my question:

I want a graph (Oscillations) to evolve in realtime during an animation. For this purpose I came up with the following. I would start from a cylinder or a cube, which I would repeatedly extrude to the next data point and set a timeframe there. My struggle is finding an access to the top face of the cube.

I also do not know yet how to extrude it to a specific coordinate but I can get around this by just translating it.

Another idea was to just spawn a very small cube at every coordinate but I did not try it out yet because I am scared my PC would crash. I have about 50 seconds and later a lot more I want to run the animation and every tenth of a second I have a data point.

Does anyone know either a way to get around this or a different method to visualize this kind of data in blender?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more specifically. Eg perhaps 3 or 4 frames of data and an image of the expected result.

Comment: I came up with another problem, this is why it took so long. I wrote the code for the cubes and I can show you what I mean as soon as I fixed this other problem. So here is the other problem first:  When I create a camera, I see only black through it. When I switch to camera view and then move from there on the whole screen is black. I can not find objects anymore. Here is the link to my project, maybe you can figure it out. http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51435